# How to slice characters from string and return count of remaining characters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have below string, i want to slice 22 characters from begining and need to display count of remaining characters.

**For Ex -** Red,Blue,ABC,Test1,REN,Green,Test,Red - Total 37 characters

**Expected Output**

Red,Blue,ABC,Test1,REN --------------- 15

Out of total 37 characters, 22 is the sliced characters and 15 is the remaining count from total string.

**Below is my code.**

```
viewMore(text) {
    if (text.values) {
      const enumText = text.values[0];
      return enumText.slice(0, 22) + (enumText.length > 22 ? enumText.length : "");
    }   
  }
```

PFA
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to subtract the sliced text length from the original text length

```
viewMore(text) {
    if (text.values) {
      const enumText = text.values[0];
      this.htmlToAdd = enumText.slice(0, 22) + (enumText.length > 22 ? "------<strong>("+(enumText.length - enumText.slice(0, 22).length)+")</strong>" : "");;
    }   
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="htmlToAdd"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of ------- i want spaces and need to display count in bold, can u help to apply css formating?

Comment: Added screenshot of output which i want, rest function is working fine.

Comment: Yeah. sure. Lemme just try it out

Comment: Can you try this out? I haven't tried this out in angular environment. But it's supposed to work

Comment: By it's not working you mean, it's not making it bolder, right??

Comment: Now I have replaced the span tag with strong tag. Now  it should make the text bolder. I have tried this out in stackBlitz. here's the output. https://angular-ivy-agyc7v.stackblitz.io

Comment: Here's the whole code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-agyc7v

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "Red,Blue,ABC,Test1,REN,Green,Test,Red";
arrayOfText = text.split('');
if(arrayOfText.length > 22) {
    var remainingChars = arrayOfText.length - 22;
    console.log(text.substring(0, 22) + ' -------- ' + remainingChars);
} else {
    console.log("");
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Assuming you need only to slice 22 characters. I haven't created exact data type as yours but you can do the rest of the modifications and see the desired output.

```js
var types = 'Red,Blue,ABC,Test1,REN,Green,Test,Red';
console.log(types.slice(0,22) +'-------------'+ (types.length - 22))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//[with ES6] --

dummyStr = "Red,Blue,ABC,Test1,REN,Green,Test,Red";
chopOffPoint = 22;
 `${dummyStr.slice(0,chopOffPoint)}----------${dummyStr.length-chopOffPoint}`;
// Hope this will help
```